# Is this a violation of Conceptual Integrity?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm building an application with several `Connector` classes that interface with varied data silos. For an example, see an earlier question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241094/encapsulating-an-expensive-resource-without-using-a-singleton). Anyways, as is the case in my example, almost all of these data sources are expensive time-wise on access, so each `Connector` maintains a cache to limit accesses. For every data silo, there is an `IDataSource` that fetches data, and a `Connector` that caches. The `Connector` is accessed by passing in an `IDataSource` to a factory method on my `AppFactory` class.

Unfortunately, there is exactly 1 `Connector` that does not fit this model. The Active Directory silo is fast enough to not need a cache, so there is no need for an `ActiveDirectoryConnector`, nor would there be a factory method on my `AppFactory` class. As I said before, in EVERY other case, data is requested from a `Connector` object, which can only be gotten from a method call to the `AppFactory` with an `IDataSource` parameter.

As far as I can tell, my options are to have a shallow `ActiveDirectoryConnector` object that just forwards requests straight to its `IActiveDirectoryDataSource`, or to not have an `ActiveDirectoryConnector` at all. In the former case, I maintain conceptual integrity with the rest of my `Connector`s, but I have a useless level of indirection. In the latter, I sacrifice conceptual integrity for directness. Which is the lesser evil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say to keep your model in place and don't introduce the complexity of the special case handling.  It's perfectly reasonable to have a `Connector` that just forwards on the request to the eventual data source.  You're not bending over backwards here, there's nothing fundamental to the `Connector` metaphor that requires it to have a cache.  The cache is just a performance optimization and the `Connector` concept seems to be a useful abstraction layer that allows you to introduce a cache (or other processing) when needed.

Conceptually this is somewhat similar to the practice of accessing member data for an object through accessor methods instead of directly using the member variable, which is considered a best practice by many.  The reason for that is similar: if you add a level of indirection in between the client and the data, it allows you to introduce additional processing or optimization in the future when that data needs to be accessed.

Comment: In a sense, it's just the degenerate case: a cache of zero size.

Comment: I really like the analogy to the accessor methods. The ActiveDirectorConnector is analogous to public Type Name{get;set;} in my mind, which validates its existence.